# how Indian children can come to Philippines together with their filipino mother?

Tags: indian-citizens, india, filipino-citizens, philippines

I am a Filipino and I want to bring my 2 children to the Philippines but they are Indian nationals, I want to ask what is the easiest way for me to bring my babies, I am not planning to bring them and let then stay there permanently just I want them to meet my family, I heard about OCI, is OCI need to change the nationality of my babies to become Filipino?

Comment: Is this a intended to be a permanent move, or just a visit? What about the childrens' father? Will he be coming too?

Comment: it is just a visit that may last 6 months to 1 year for the children and for the father he will just come for about 20 days because he will go again to other countries for his job..

Comment: OCI is something they might get _after_ gaining another nationality, in order to return to India.

Comment: They are already Indian citizen, it means they need to be Filipino first in their passport in order to apply OCI, thank brothers!